# Django How to retrieve data based on their pk

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I want a staff Dashboard which can see all user data and also CRUD it. how can I dynamically filter for the pk of the user data. If I use objects.all I get everything but cant edit specific values

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import UserPassesTestMixin
class AdminStaffRequiredMixin(LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin):

    def test_func(self):
        return self.request.user.is_superuser or self.request.user.is_staff




class Dashboard (AdminStaffRequiredMixin, LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = SchulverzeichnisTabelle
    template_name = 'SCHUK/Dashboard.html'
    context_object_name = 'Dashboard'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Schulverzeichnis'] = SchulverzeichnisTabelle.objects.all()


        return context
```

Comment: You edit with an `UpdateView`.

Answer (score 0):

You edit an item with an [**`UpdateView`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.UpdateView), so:

```
from django.views.generic import UpdateView


class DashboardView(AdminStaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = SchulverzeichnisTabelle
    template_name = 'SCHUK/Dashboard.html'
    context_object_name = 'Schulverzeichnis'


class SchulverzeichnisUpdateView(AdminStaffRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = SchulverzeichnisTabelle
    template_name = 'SCHUK/edit_schulverzeichnis.html'
```

In the `url.py` you make then an entry to *edit* the item:

```
# app_name/urls.py

from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('dashboard/', DashboardView.as_view()),
    path(
        'dashboard/schulverzeichnis/<int:pk>/edit/',
        SchulverzeichnisUpdateView.as_view(),
        name='edit-schulverzeichnis',
    ),
]
```

In your `DashboardView` template, you then link to the edit for that view:

```
<a href="{% url 'edit-schulverzeichnis' pk=obj.pk %}">edit</a>
```

with `obj` the object that you use in the `ListView`. In the `edit_schulverzeichnis.html` template, you then can use the `{{ form }}` and submit a POST request to the same view to update.

---

> **Note**: Models normally have no `Tabelle` suffix. A model is not a table, it is stored in a relational database as a table, but even then it has extra logic like validators, managers, etc.

---

> **Note**: In Django, class-based views (CBV) often have a `…View` suffix, to avoid a clash with the model names.
> Therefore you might consider renaming the view class to `DashboardView`, instead of <s>`Dashboard`</s>.

Comment: I think I need to repost my question. I have it like that, my actual goal is to retrieve all user data from his pk. Like the user has one school(schulverzeichnis) and also many teachers and I want in the dashboard all of the teachers and the school from the user shown and based on that I can CRUD it as a staff user

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your model, and how it related to user, but I can imagine:

```
class Dashboard (...):

    # any staff here

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['Schulverzeichnis'] = SchulverzeichnisTabelle.objects.filter(author=self.request.user)
        return context
```

By the way, try to use only English language in code. If you start to work in team, this knowledge helps.

Comment: Im sorry, I wanted to do this in english much simpler but the client want it like that. Can I also filter by individual user not the own user id ? like in my comment above

Comment: you can filter by different parametes.